# Crashlytics migration for Firebase ruins Twitter functionality from Fabric

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, google-fabric

I'm using the Twitter kit from Firebase

```
TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(BuildConfig.TW_CUSTOMER_KEY, BuildConfig.TW_CUSTOMER_SECRET);
Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig), new TwitterCore(authConfig), new TweetUi());
```

But I've migrated Crashlytics to Firebase. Firebase doesn't work if I keep having the key in the manifest

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="9249a2692d5c8xxxxxxxxxxxxxc" />
```

Problem is that if I remove it, I can't use Twitter anymore, it crashes with `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must start Twitter Kit with Fabric.with() first android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity`

Is there a solution for this ?! I can't find a middle ground to support both of 'em.

Comment: are you check fabric to firebase migration codes?its seems to firebase json error

Comment: i've added the json file to the app. the thing is that if I uncomment the thing in the manifest, Firebase crashlytics works just fine. If i put it back, twitter starts working again but Firebase doesn't

Comment: Former Fabric/Firebase DA here - Twitter removed support of that SDK on Oct 31, 2018 - https://blog.twitter.com/developer/en_us/topics/tools/2018/discontinuing-support-for-twitter-kit-sdk.html You should see that post for other solutions

Answer (score 1):

Twitter kit is no longer part of Fabric or Crashlytics. However, it is available through the Twitter Developer site. Check there for how to update your SDKs.

Comment: Can I use the firebase twitter login for the same